# Loading HTML file in to popover

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

HTML markup:

```
<li tabindex='+len+' rel="popover" class="pop" data-placement="left"></li>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".pop").popover({
    title: 'To Load',
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        $.get('templates/workInProcessDetail.html').success(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    }
});
```

Please help me out it is not loading.

Comment: please provide more details or an example fiddle.

Comment: Try to add a title attribute on your element.

Comment: here is the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/szkrx/65/

Answer (score 0):

You could return an iframe

```
content: function () {
        return '<iframe src="templates/workInProcessDetail.html" style="border:none"></iframe>';
    }
```